# Im trying to create a sticky nav using bootsrap4, But it's not working properly

Tags: bootstrap-4

Hello i'm trying to use bootstrap 4 sticky nav to float it on all pages,but it's not working properly.Below is the snippet for the same

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark  sticky-top">
  <!-- One of the primary actions on mobile is to call a business - This displays a phone button on mobile only -->
  <a class="navbar-brand ml-3 small-screen" href="#" style="padding: 10px">
    <img src="http://www.510families.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/480px-wide/iciicecream.jpg" style="width: 90px;height: 80px;">
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-toggler-right">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column " id="navbar">

    <ul class="navbar-nav  w-100 justify-content-center nav1 px-3" style="padding:0px!important">
      <li style="padding-right:30px; background-color: #922C7F">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">BOOK AN APPOINTMENT</a>
      </li>
      <li style="padding-right:35px; background-color: #7B2068">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">BOOK A Table</a>
      </li>
      <li style="padding-right:40px; background-color: #631053">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">FIND A Person</a>
      </li>
      <li style="padding-right:8px; background-color: #ED1C24">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="padding-right:0px;">
          <i class="fas fa-phone-square" style="font-size: 20px;color:black"></i>&nbsp Contact
          <span style="font-weight: bold">617 98 22344</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li style="padding-right:32px; background-color: #922C7F">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">search</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center w-100 nav2 px-3" style="padding:0px">
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link nav-menu2" href="#" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px">WHY ME?
          <span style="padding: 3px">|</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link nav-menu2 dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px">OUR SPECIALITIES</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link nav-menu2" href="#" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px">
          <span style="padding: 3px">|</span> FOR PERSONS
          <span style="padding: 3px">|</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link nav-menu2" href="#" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px">
          FOR PROFESSIONALS
          <span style="padding: 3px">|</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-menu2" href="#" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px">
          CAREERS
          <span style="padding: 3px">|</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-menu2" href="#" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px">
          REACH US
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I want float my logo and navbar through out the page. How can i achieve that?.
my nav bar should be on image and there will be two nav bars so i created two ul

[Please check my code](https://codepen.io/ravanone/pen/MXMmVr)

Comment: would you mind if i add some jquery to it?

Comment: Use  `positon: fixed;`  instead of sticky. Check [this](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/MXMoEZ) out. Do the necessary stylings and that would do. If this doesn't work ping me up ill show you another way using jquery.

Comment: @Mohammedwahedkhan  jquery is fine with. If i use position fixed, i need to change complete style for that.Looking for other solution. last choice is fixed nav

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, then you need to put the `navbar-brand` inside the `navbar`.

### Code Fix

```
<div class="container" style="padding: 0px">

    <div class="image-container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark  sticky-top">
          <a class="navbar-brand ml-3 large-screen" href="#" style="float: left;background-color: white;padding: 10px">
              <img src="http://www.510families.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/480px-wide/iciicecream.jpg" style="width: 150px;height: 130px;;">
          </a>


            <!-- One of the primary actions on mobile is to call a business - This displays a phone button on mobile only -->
            <a class="navbar-brand ml-3 small-screen" href="#" style="padding: 10px">
                <img src="http://www.510families.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/480px-wide/iciicecream.jpg" style="width: 90px;height: 80px;">
            </a>
```

### Old Code

```
<div class="container" style="padding: 0px">

    <div class="image-container">
        <a class="navbar-brand ml-3 large-screen" href="#" style="float: left;background-color: white;padding: 10px">
            <img src="http://www.510families.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/480px-wide/iciicecream.jpg" style="width: 150px;height: 130px;;">
        </a>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark  sticky-top">
            <!-- One of the primary actions on mobile is to call a business - This displays a phone button on mobile only -->
            <a class="navbar-brand ml-3 small-screen" href="#" style="padding: 10px">
                <img src="http://www.510families.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/480px-wide/iciicecream.jpg" style="width: 90px;height: 80px;">
            </a>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/tentacular261/pen/WyqOrd?editors=1100)

### Tips

These are mostly my opinion(feel free to ignore them), but your code could really use a cleanup. Let's take this example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .small-screen {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This is verbose and confusing:

1. Combine `.small-screen` with `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu` under the same
   `@media (...)` media rule.
2. `@media (min-width: 768px)` applies to screen *larger* than 768px, but you have the class `.small-screen` be applied to these larger sized screens. At the very least, this is confusing.
3. Using more bootstrap utilities will help readability and conciseness. In this instance, the `d-md-none` can replace the `.small-screen` class.

These three points apply specifically to this code example, but also apply generally to much of your other code. Reviewing your code with these points in mind will help your code be maintainable/readable by others and yourself.